# Error in factor(variable) : object 'variable' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am actually quite new to the R software (currently using R 3.5.0) and have recently encountered an error message when attempting to create a forest plot. I would greatly appreciate a potential solution to this issue.

Again, the error message states: Error in factor(variable) : object 'variable' not found.

Also, please find below the codes that I have used.

```
Z.test <- read.csv(file = "C://Users//yli33//Desktop//Figure_CDCR.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("90th vs 50th"), Z = 0)

Z.test$MeAT <- factor(Z.test$MeAT, levels = c("1"), labels=c("A. 90th vs 50th"))

Z <- ggplot(Z.test, aes(factor(variable), Risk)) +
geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="blue") +
geom_errorbar(width=.05, aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper)) +
facet_wrap(~ MeAT, ncol = 3, scales = "fixed")

Z + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) , labels=c("C_others","C_others_M","C_others_F","C_migrant","C_migrant_M","C_migrant_F","C_seasonal","C_seasonal_M","C_seasonal_F"))+
labs (x = "Patient characteristics", y = "Percent change in risk of clinic visit") +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(2,2,size=10), axis.title.x = element_text(2,2,size=10),
axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.7, size=8, color='black'),
axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.7, size=7,color='black'),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="white" )) +
geom_hline(data = dummy2, aes(yintercept = Z), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the column names of your dataframe `Z.test` just before you get this error? Your process is trying to find a column named `variable`.

Comment: Also, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=votes&pageSize=30) for examples of how to post data on stack overflow. You're more likely to get help with troubleshooting questions if people can see your data and reproduce your problem/error

Comment: R is case sensitive, so "variable" and "Variable"  are different.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the helpful responses (especially Dave2e's reminder that R is case sensitive). That definitely resolved the issue once I changed my code to read 'Variable'. Thanks again!